# Just in time compiled Foreign function Interface: what is it that gets "runtime" compiled

Tags: c, lua, jit, ffi, luajit

My question is about JIT'ing foreign function interfaces in general, but I will use LuaJIT as a specific example. It is said that LuaJIT's FFI is faster than binding to C directly because calls to the C functions can get JIT compiled.

Could anyone explain this. Typically, the C function being bound already exists in a library so it has already been compiled, so what exactly gets JIT'ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[LuaJIT extensions: the FFI Library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html)**
>
> [...] The code generated by the JIT-compiler for accesses to C data structures from Lua code is on par with the code a C compiler would generate. *Calls to C functions can be inlined in JIT-compiled code, unlike calls to functions bound via the classic Lua/C API.*

In response to your question of what gets compiled, it's just that: the *calls* to C functions. In fact, calls to C functions via the classic C API will **never** be compiled, even in a future version of LuaJIT. They will raise [NYI](http://wiki.luajit.org/NYI#Bytecode) messages, causing any traces to abort and effectively preventing surrounding Lua code from being compiled. For example, a classic C function call `FUNCC` opcode within a loop will prevent that loop from being compiled. This just means that LuaJIT will fall back to its interpreter, which is still quite fast.

To reiterate, LuaJIT does not perform any magic on already-compiled C code. It simply inlines FFI calls to C functions within JIT assembly code.

Comment: In the interpreter its still a function call from C to C, so not that expensive right ? or is it that LuaJIT also compiles some surrounding code that provides the extra benefit. On "inlines FFI calls" it does not inline the C function right, that would be difficult without the source.

Comment: The LuaJIT interpreter is hand-written in assembly for each different architecture that it supports. Basically, to go from the interpreter to the JIT compiler is to go from assembly and some C to assembly streamlined for your Lua code, and anything that raises a NYI flag will prevent that from happening. There's much more information about this on the LuaJIT website as well as in the source code. You might want to play around with `luajit -jdump` to see what it produces and get a feel for how the compiler works.